# How to get URL pointing to specific candidate in Workday from WID

Tags: workday-api

I've been try to figure out a way to get a URL pointing to a candidate's profile in Workday given a candidate's WID. My scenario is that I use the `Put_Candidate` operation (Workday Web Services SOAP API) to create a candidate which lets me know the `WID` and the `Candidate_ID` of the created candidate. From this returned information, I was hoping to construct the URL to the created candidate's profile in Workday. Is this possible? I'd appreciate any help/guidance that anyone can provide regarding this sort of scenario. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I know its a little late, but if you are still looking for an answer then you can use
Get_workers api in Humar Resource Module and frame a request as below:-

`<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:bsvc="urn:com.workday/bsvc">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
         <wsse:UsernameToken>
            <wsse:Username>your username</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">your password</wsse:Password>
         </wsse:UsernameToken>
      </wsse:Security>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <wd:Get_Workers_Request xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc" version="set appropriate version here">
           <wd:Request_References bsvc:Skip_Non_Existing_Instances="false">
               <wd:Worker_Reference >
                   <wd:ID wd:type="WID">Populate WID here</wd:ID>
               </wd:Worker_Reference>
           </wd:Request_References>
      </wd:Get_Workers_Request>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>`